# how to make a div stay in a div

Tags: html, css, css-position, game-physics

I'm making a pong clone using HTML/CSS/Js. I've set a div element to act as a border for the game, just to keep things in a confined space. How do I get elements (for example, a scoreboard) to act relative to their parent element? For example, if I tell the child to move 50% left, it moves to the center of the parent-div, and NOT to the center of the web-page. Basically I want the child confined by the dimensions of their parent (haha). It seems like

```
child-div {
   position:relative;
}
```

in CSS would do the trick, but it's not...maybe it's because I'm developing in CodeAcademy's IDE?

Comment: Anyone else confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:relative` means **relative to itself** not parents/children etc. It seems likely that you want relative on the parent and possibly absolute on the children. Without code, it's hard to help much further

Here's a quick demo for you.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
.scoreboard {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  /* just for a bit of space */
  left: 50%;
  /*almost centered*/
  margin-left: -100px;
  /* half of known width */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scoreboard"></div>
</div>
```

Note...there are other centering methods for absolutely positioned divs depending on whether the width is known and browser support requirements

`left: 50%;` does **not** center an element...it moves the element's top/left corner to the center of the containing element. You have to move it back half of it's width (if known)...see above.

One final point....positioned elements are not **constrained** to their ancestor elements but rather positioned in relation to them. It's quite common to have positioned elements **outside** the bounds of parents.